# Updating the value of a dynamically inserted table

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have written a code to dynamically insert the table rows.I have used insertRow() and insertCell() method. If i want to change(update) the value of a dynamically created cell , how can I do that?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to post some code in your question.

Comment: `table.rows[rownum].cells[colnum].innerHTML = newvalue`

Comment: working Barmar.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the values using **`innerHTML`**. Do it as below..

```
var table=document.getElementById("your_table_id");
var row=table.insertRow(1);
var cell0=row.insertCell(0);
var cell1=row.insertCell(1);
cell0.style.border="none";
cell1.style.border="none";
cell0.innerHTML="your new value";
cell1.innerHTML="<div class='content'><input type='text'/>you can have anything here like div, input etc..</div>
```

Try it..

Comment: I already have some data in the cells.I want to change those values in some other function.how to do that?

Comment: make for eg, cell0 and cell1 global and then you can access these variables from anywhere and in the new functionuse the same code as above and change the value..

Comment: did you get it @abhaysachu ???

Comment: Thankyou @abhaysachu..:) happy Coding..!! and Happy new year.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "onchange" event of the input field where you get the numbers.

and onchange you can call a function to set the dimensions of the table.